# What stuff are to be placed inside the "core" application subdirectory?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Under the `application` directory there is the `core` directory. When downloading `CodeIgniter` for the first time then there is just the `index.html` file there. So what files should be placed there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this directory to store Controllers and Models that can be extended by other classes. For example

**application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller { ...... }
```

**application/controllers/Products.php**

```
class Products extends MY_Controller { ...}
```

You can do the same with Models.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html